# When I close socket connection client continue working?

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

I am new to JAVA Sockets, I just want to make app, that receives some string value. I guess, server works fine. It sends data 5 times seperatly and stops. But client receive server's messages not separatly, even more,
when server stops client DONT, client dont stops and still receive messages (NULL)

SERVER

```
static BufferedReader in; 
    static BufferedWriter out; 
    static Socket clientSocket;

    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        try {
            clientSocket = new Socket("192.168.0.106", 13130);

            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream()));
            int i = 0;
            while (!clientSocket.isClosed()) {
                System.out.println("Times: " + i++);
                String cmd = in.readLine();
                System.out.println(cmd);
            }
            clientSocket.close();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
```

And Server

```
void Write() throws Exception{
        ServerSocket serverSocket;
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(13130);

        Socket clientSocket;
        System.out.println("Listening...");
        clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        // и отправлять
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream()));

        Thread.sleep(10000);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

            System.out.println("Times: " + i);
            out.write("Hello " + i);
            out.flush();

        }
        clientSocket.close();
        serverSocket.close();
    }
```

So, I expected that the client read data 5 times and will stop.
But I got next output:

```
Times: 0
Hello 0Hello 1Hello 2Hello 3Hello 4
Times: 1
null
Times: 2
null
Times: 3
null
Times: 4
null
Times: 5
null
Times: 6
null
AND SO ON...
```

Maybe problem: server sends messages too fast?

Comment: Closing a socket doesn't magically cause `isClosed()` at the other end to become true. That method only tells you whether *you* have closed *this socket.* You should be testing the result of `readLine()` for null instead.

Comment: @user207421  Thanks, but how i can read sended massages separatly?

Comment: You are reading lines but you aren't writing lines. Add a line terminator.